# Grabbing a selected number of images from a site with Jsoup

Tags: image, jsoup, extract

I require the first 5 images of type jpg from 3 different sites. Currently i am using:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).timeout(10*1000).get();
Elements jpgs = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]");
```

To grab the jpgs from a single site and save them into an ArrayList and then add them to a JPanel. This means i can only use one site however i would like to have mixed results of the images from 3 (or more) sites.

Using .first and then writing code to ignore the previously grabbed elements would be one option but is not very clean.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, it would just entail adding the sites you want to get content from to an ArrayList.

Connect to a site, append the number of images you want to `ArrayList images`, then repeat this process for each site you want to get content from.

```
ArrayList<String> sites = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();  
sites.add("http://google.com);
sites.add("http://facebook.com");
sites.add("http://stackoverflow.com");
int numSites = sites.size();

//number of images you want from each site
int maxNum = 5; 

for (int i = 0; i < numSites; i++) {
      //iterate through images and save first 5 or however many you choose
      for (Elements jpg : jpgs) {
      while (maxNum > 0) {
         images.add(jpg.attr("abs:src"));
         maxNum--;
      }
}
```

Then connect to the next site and repeat this process for how ever many sites you want to get content from.

Hope this helps.